# AEM 6.1 client context error while configuring Test and target

Tags: runtime-error, target, aem

While configuring Test and target i have to include the client context to my site.
Now  I am getting below error in error.log. There are no issues in the functionality but i can see following lines in the error logs(user admin, local author environment(AEM6.1))

```
18.01.2016 09:36:47.107 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1453070207104] GET /etc/segmentation.segment.js HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension js, cannot render resource JcrNodeResource, type=rep:ACL, superType=null, path=/etc/segmentation/aam/rep:policy


18.01.2016 09:36:47.108 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1453070207104] GET /etc/segmentation.segment.js HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension js, cannot render resource JcrNodeResource, type=rep:ACL, superType=null, path=/etc/segmentation/rep:policy
```

I am not using AAM(Adobe Audience Manager) so why it is trying to include that node? Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the home page of your site  Change WCM mode to design mode and
   configure the Segment Path to the test and target segmentation path 
   in your instance.
2. Go to the /etc/clientcontext/custom_context/content.html ad delete
   all the component which you are not using.